# how to go to another page with a button click with ionic?

Tags: button, ionic-framework, navigation

I have been trying to work with the code, I added the button but I don't know how to link it to another page when clicking on it.

Comment: To open a new page a few months of experience with the framework are needed.

Answer (score 13):

html:

```
 <ion-buttons>
   <button ion-button (click)="goAnOtherPage()">Go an Other Page </button>
 </ion-buttons>
```

OR

```
 <ion-label  [navPush]="anOtherPage">Go an Other Page</ion-label>
```

in TS:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AnOtherPage } from '/anOtherPage';


anOtherPage: AnOtherPage;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

goAnOtherPage() {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(anOtherPage);
}
```

Comment: I did not understand, you can write more in detail?

Comment: I just pasted the code, but did not work, used this.navCtrl.push(AnOtherPage) inside a function

Comment: I have put the files in https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQoc3zSB4CupvWJzH5Ex-0UFngqhnMmwocsrx2xWXXmxzpQ49c6T9EvvGHy7-OOMQwh__RzhSSS4BZt/pub

Comment: go Ask Question and write your code, I will answer you

Comment: Property 'setRoot' does not exist on type 'NavController'.ts(2339). Any other option?

Answer (score 11):

html

```
<ion-button (click)="nextpage()">Home</ion-button>
```

ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


constructor(private route: Router) { }

  nextpage() {
    this.route.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Navigation works differently in ionic and it is not advised to simply use an anchor tag and the path to the file.

Here is an example which works. In the relevant TS file import the page(s) you want to navigate to like so

```
import { OtherPage} from "../pagefolder/pagecontroler";
import { YetAnotherPage} from "../pagefolder/pagecontroler";
```

Ensure that you have the navigation controller imported and injected into the constructor of your current TS file. It should look like the following in case you are not sure.

```
import { NavController } from "ionic-angular";
```

Then in constructor

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, .....) {

}
```

Once you have the navigation controller and the page(s) imported you can proceed to create a function like so

```
navigateToOtherPage(): void {
   this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);
}
```

That completes the navigation setup for your TS file.
Now you go to the relevant template you want to navigate from and you can use any tags you want for instance

```
<button (click)="navigateToOtherPage()">Next Page<button>
```

or you can use an a, span or div in a similar way

```
<a (click)="navigateToOtherPage()">Other Page</a>
<span (click)="navigateToOtherPage()">Other Page</span>
<div (click)="navigateToOtherPage()">Other Page</div>
```

You don't necessarily have to use the click event you can use whatever event you want. The main things are that you have the navigation controller imported and injected in your constructor as shown above and you have the page(s) you want to navigate to imported as well and you only use the navigation controller to push pages you want to navigate to.

Answer (score 2):

For Ionic 5 - below code is working for me, with **Ionic 5 + Angular 9** combination,

**Step 1** - In html file, add the code to "define" the function,

```
<ion-button (click)="gotoHomePage()">Go to Homepage</ion-button>
```

**Step 2** - In the constructor of your class, you can Inject the `NavController` - Injecting NavController will always get you an instance of the nearest `NavController`, regardless of whether it is a Tab or a Nav.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }
```

**Step 3** - In TS file for your component, add the method that you are calling on click of ion-button,

```
gotoHomePage() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('home');
  }
```

Here the 'home' is defined route in your `app-routing.module.ts` file, like below,

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule) },
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use angular to do this for you:

```
<button ng-click="doSomething(withSomebody)"> Submit
</button>
```

You would need to have a controller to and define **doSomething()**

```
$scope.doSomething=function(somebody){
    ...insert code here
}
```

If you needed to change your state, the inject $state into your controller and use **$state.go(stateName)**

ref: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would navigate to a different page in the same way as if you were in Angular.

Important thing to remember is that **Ionic routes are essentially Angular routes**. 
To learn more about how they work, visit: https://angular.io/guide/router

To answer your question.

Let's imagine you want to redirect a user to your About page.

Within your **app-routing.module.ts** you have a path that goes:

```js
{
    path: 'about',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/about/about.module').then( m => m.AboutPageModule)
  }
```

Then in the tags of a button, you want add the classical Angular router call that goes like this:

```html
<ion-button color="dark" expand="block" fill="outline" routerLink="/about">Go!</ion-button>
```

Basically, **routerLink="/*name-of-the-path*"** can be used on your buttons or  tags to redirect the user to the desired location.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code in Ionic 4 to go one page to another page:

```
<ion-button expand="block" routerLink="/dashboard" routerDirection="root">Home</ion-button>
```

(routerLink) to set the page name to when you go to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple way:

```
 <ion-button routerLink="/myPageName" routerDirection="root">
 Go to myPageName!
 </ion-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions I have tried don't work, but this one below it does for me.

To go from home page to another page just watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paRZyKDHPak

in the home.page.ts file add

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
```

set the constructor

```
constructor(public router:Router) {}
```

create the function

```
redirectToOther(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('other');
 }
```

you guys can add a "go back button" to go back to the home page just adding this HMTL code in other.page.html, that's it

```
<ion-buttons slot="start"><ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button></ion-buttons>
```

Comment: Are you the author of the video?

Comment: No I'm not but I posted as I found it super useful as others on that channel

Answer (score 0):

You can call a route like this.

```
<button onclick="location.href='/pageToRoute/param'" block>
</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

This is what i used

```
 <ion-nav-buttons side="right" >
        <a href="templates/yourpage.html">
        <button class="button">
            Show your page
        </button>
        </a>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
```

Answer (score -13):

Place button inside anchor tag.

```
 <a href="path of the file"><button>Name</button></a>
```

You can also refer this link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp