# how i link different pages in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I am stuck to link different pages by **Anchor tag** without using **Angular**. I tried following kind of code:

```
 <ul class="menu-contents">
   <li>
     <a href="../resume/resume.html">
      <ion-icon  ios="ios-paper" md="md-paper" ></ion-icon> Resume Builder</a>
```

But its not working correctly. How to set routs?

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/NavPush/). Navigation in Ionic is kind of different ([docs reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation)). You could use `<a [navPush]="YourPageName">`. I'm not sure of this is what you're looking for, let me know if it is, and I'll add an answer with more details.

Comment: And this is where Angular2..4 and Ionic differ too! See here for Angular https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-2-without-ionic-2-part-1/

Comment: Take a look at this answer. You should be able to follow it and get the 3 pages linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245847/how-to-go-to-another-page-with-a-button-click-with-ionic/49463055#49463055