# Ionic 3 - Clickable Card - Redirect

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, frontend

I have difficulty creating a box in Ionic 3 that is clickable, specifically when calling the function inside TypeScript. How do I call the box click function and get redirected to another page?

See below the box I created.

```
<div class="boxes">
    <ion-card **(click)="pageClick(pos)**">
      <br>
      <ion-icon name="tablet-portrait"> </ion-icon>
      <ion-card-header> POS Digital</ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>Gerencie seu negócio online no POS Digital da GetNet com a Valeti. Gestão Online com
        segurança e confiabilidade da maior plataforma do mercado.</ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Victorzumbano, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please feel free to search about related topics. I have a solution for you here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40245847/3332734

Comment: Thanks a lot Francis. I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this existed back then in Ionic 3, but I just stumbeled across the same issue in Ionic 7.
Here you can make a card clickable by setting `type="button"` and `:button="true"`.
Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/card#button